# SQL Query to get data from one table where a specific column equals value from other table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables containing the following columns (subset of columns relative to this question)

```
Name: ORDERS
order_id
order_number
grand_total

Name: PURCHASE_ORDERS
purchase_order_id
order_number
supplier
```

Basically I am creating a search function that can filter out rows in a `DataGridView` based on input and I was wondering how I get a query which would return the following:

***pseudocode example -***

> select * from orders WHERE order_number = (select order_number from
>   purchase_orders where supplier = 'test')

sometimes more than one order number can be returned from the `purchase_orders` table so will that influence the above query?

Comment: Check for 'IN' usage, you ll get what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
SELECT* 
   from orders 
WHERE 
   order_number 
IN (SELECT 
       order_number 
    FROM
       purchase_orders 
    WHERE supplier = 'test')
```

See: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    orders
WHERE order_number IN (SELECT order_number FROM purchase_orders WHERE supplier = 'test')
```

Or Better

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    orders
    LEFT OUTER JOIN purchase_orders ON purchase_orders.order_number = orders.order_number
WHERE
    purchase_orders.supplier = 'test'
```